# Whatsapp "last seen" issue?

Tags: whatsapp-messenger

When I click on an individual chat and it reads "last seen at 8:30," does that mean that is that last time they looked at our chat?

Answer (score 1):

"Last seen at XX:XX" shows when they last were using Whatsapp, not necessarily in your chat.

Answer (score 1):

As [WhatsApp FAQ](https://www.whatsapp.com/faq/en/general/20971848) say:

> Last seen refers to the last time the contact used WhatsApp.